# intent getSerializableExtra ClassCastException

Tags: java, android, android-intent

In my app I have this line:

```
Item item = (Item)getIntent().getSerializableExtra(ITEM_TRANSFER);
```

The error I get is:  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to com.example.shop.Item

Item Class implements Serializable so I don't know what the problem is.

```
@Override

public void onItemClick(View view, int position){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ItemDetailActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(ITEM_TRANSFER, mRecyclerViewAdapter.getItemId(position) );
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This is how I use Extra

Comment: show code that puts extra in the intent when you're starting the activity

Comment: `getItemId()` returns a `long`, the exception message makes it very clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send  `Item` value instead your passing `getItemId()`

```
@Override

public void onItemClick(View view, int position){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ItemDetailActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(ITEM_TRANSFER, item);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Receive

```
Item item = (Item)getIntent().getSerializableExtra(ITEM_TRANSFER);
```